# Requesting API Content on Localhost while using Tor + Privoxy

Tags: python, proxy, tor, privoxy

I'm using Tor, Privoxy, and Python to anonymously crawl sources on the web.  Tor is configured with `ControlPort 9051`, while Privoxy is configured with `forward-socks5 / localhost:9050 .`

My scripts are working flawlessly, except when I request an API resource that I have running on `8000` on the same machine. If I hit the API via urllib2 setup with the proxy, I get an empty string response. If I hit the API using a new, non-proxy instance of urllib2, I get a **HTTP Error 503: Forwarding failure**.

I'm sure that if I open 8000 to the world I'll be able to access the port through the proxy. However, there must be a better way to access the resource on localhost. Curious how people deal with this.

Comment: 503 Forwarding Error would imply that the proxy is still in use.  Are you sure the urllib2 instance accessing localhost isn't somehow using the proxy?

Comment: Yes, I suppose it's still in use. The question, then, is how to make requests outside of tor, as one would normally, while still running it for other requests. Step 1 - Get resource using tor. Step 2 - Parse resource. Step 3 - Hit internal API.

Comment: Think I might be able to set urllib2.ProxyHandler() to localhost

Answer (score 0):

I was able to switch off proxy and hit internal API by using the following to opener:

```
        ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
        ctx.check_hostname = False
        ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPSHandler(context=ctx))
        urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

I'm not sure if there is a better way, but it worked.